# Installing a package to a specific relative directory with pip

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I have several packages that I need to install in a directory like this:

../site-packages/mynamespace/packages

Mainly, this is for historical reasons so imports don't break.

There are several such packages and we would need to be able to pick and choose which package we need based on the needs of the project.

So, this all needs to happen in the requirements.txt file, so something like this in the requirements.txt

```
requests
celery
beautifulsoup4
path/to/mypackage1
path/to/mypackage3
path/to/mypackage5
```

(for example)

And then I need

```
path/to/mypackage1
path/to/mypackage3
path/to/mypackage5
```

to be installed to:

```
../site-packages/mynamespace/packages
```

Accordingly, would mypackage1, mypackage3, and mypacakge5 all to be available from

```
from mynamespace.packages import mypackage1 #(and 3 and 5)
```

So far what I've tried to do is create a site.cfg file to go along with the setup.py, but I think pip might be creating it's own install values and bypassing the site.cfg, that looks like this:

```
[install]
install-base=$HOME
install-purelib=Lib\site-packages\mynamespace\packages
```

Also, each environment runs in a virtual environment.

I thought of having two separate requirements files to run, but this isn't workable. I need to have all the packages in a single requirements.txt file that is invoked simply by pip install -r requirements.txt

I thought of having them install directly to site-packages and then adding the imports to `mynamespace.packages.__init__.py` but this is also isn't workable. The packages need to physically be located under site-pacakges.mynamespace.packages.

Furthermore, --target will not work for me because A.) this is absolute path only (relative paths work, but this is based on where the user is currently located) B.) this violates the above requirement of a single requirements.txt file (otherwise requests, etc would all go to the other directory)

I'm thinking there must be some way to hack site.cfg.

Ideally, if I could add --target=relative_path within the requirements.txt that would solve my problem, but I don't think this is possible. Only a few options are allowed within a requirements file (-e being one) but not -t. Even so, it would have to be relative based on the site-packages directory used for the install and not relative where the user is located.

Also, this needs to work in all operating systems.

Thank you